# Can't boot Asus Zenbook UX390U

Tags: boot, laptop, bios, asus-laptop

My Asus Zenbook UX390U entered the bios by itself and then froze. I had to turn the laptop off by holding the power button. After that the laptop no longer turns on and the bios cannot be entered. The power light (and capslock light) turn on, and the screen flickers for a fraction of a second. Holding the power button for 60 seconds doesn't fix anything. I've opened up and unplugged the battery. There's no detachable CMOS battery.

I assume the bios is corrupt. Any ideas what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing RAM, CPU, or dislodged adapter. In any case. You may want to attempt a couple things.

- make sure that the CPU is not overheating. Check the thermal grease between the CPU, and the heat riser. Also ensure the (CPU) fan is spinning fast enough, and that the airflow is not restricted (dust/lint on fan, or around vent(s). Same for the GPU.
- Ensure that the CPU (if removable) is *fully* inserted, and *locked*
- Ensure that *all* the RAM is *firmly* seated.
- As a last resort, reset the BIOS by placing a shunt in the appropriate position, as prescribed by the user manual for your laptop. Removing the (internal) battery (as available) will also help. They all have a `CMOS` battery. Some are more difficult than others to locate, or identify.

Comment: I'll take another look for the CMOS battery, but I couldn't see one anywhere as everything is soldered to the board

Comment: @tic In case it helps. Not *all* `CMOS` batteries appear to be a battery. Sometimes they are combined with the `PIC` and or `RTC`. So they'll be a socketed "dip" chip -- Dual Inline Pins. Or, even worse, *combined* with the `BIOS`. In which case, you'll need to remove it, and let it stand (out of the laptop) for some 24hrs. In hopes of it *discharging* before returning it to its socket. **Warning**: they're not always "keyed". So take *careful* note of its orientation before removing.

Comment: "Or, even worse, combined with the BIOS" - Do you have a link to an image of what this looks like?

Comment: Regrettably (for you) no. I'm afraid all of this comes from actual experiences I have had. Does your Zenbook not come with a manual? Maybe a service manual can be found online?

Comment: Strangely I can't even find existence of this 1 year old laptop online. It only shows the UX390UA which looks reasonably dissimilar to the one I own